# Let S be an uncountable subset of a separable metric space (X,d). Then,can we find any such S in X which contains no dense subset D, dense in itself?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

This question arrived into my mind after  observing the fact that many of the uncountable subsets is either dense or posseses a dense subset, dense in itself, even the Cantor set in R is perfect .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since a subspace of a separable metric space is separable, we may as well assume that $S=X$. The answer is yes, any uncountable separable metric space $S$ contains an uncountable subset which is dense in itself. To see this write $S=C\cup D$ where $x\in C$ if some neighborhood of $x$ is countable, $x\in D$ if every neighborhood of $x$ is uncountable. Now it is easy to see that $C$ is countable (from the Lindelöf property of separable metric spaces); it follows that $D$ is uncountable, and every neighborhood of a point $x\in D$ contains uncountably many points of $D$.